# How do you display a user's User Group?

Tags: templating, users

This seems simple, but I cannot get it to render -- how do display a user's User Group? Assuming I set the user in segment 2:

```
{% set thePartner = craft.users.username( craft.request.getSegment(2) ) %}
This Is My User Group: {% ???? %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UserModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#getGroups) has a [getGroups()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel) function which:

> Returns an array of
>   [UserGroupModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usergroupmodel)
>   objects that the user belongs to.

Since a user can belong to multiple usergroups, you have to loop through the array containing them:

```twig
{% set thePartner = craft.users.username( craft.request.getSegment(2) ) %}

# Loop through array of UserGroupModels #
{% for group in thePartner.getGroups() %}
    # Print name of current UserGroupModel #
    {{ group.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you are sure the user only belongs to one group, you can fetch the first UserGroupModel from like this:

```twig
{% set thePartner = craft.users.username( craft.request.getSegment(2) ) %}

# Get first UserGroupModel #
{% set group = thePartner.getGroups().first %}

# Print name #
{{ group.name }}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you -- that did the trick nicely.